# How can I check this numbers? c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have some text that looks  like this:

```
Number:12345678  
Status:FAIL  
Date:10/26/2016 4:33 PM  
Number:11111117    
Status:FAIL  
Date:10/26/2016 4:52 PM  
Number:11111115  
Status:PASS  
Date:10/26/2016 4:58 PM
```

Is there a way to check the number that has the most recent date and if was PASS return a messagebox with "1" and if was fail return a messagebox with "0"?

I started something like this, but I'm stuck. I don't know how to compare all those datetimes from textfile with datetime.now. And the text doesn't stay like that , the numbers and datetimes keep updating.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        List<string> find = new List<string>();  
        string datetime;  
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("C:\\Temp\\PASS-FAIL STATUS.txt"))  
        {  
            while ((datetime = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
            {  
                if (datetime.Contains("Date"))  
                {  
                    find.Add(datetime);  
                }  
            }  
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: Welcome. You should read [ask], and then come back and [edit] your question to explain more clearly what you're asking and include your efforts to solve it yourself. You should also include a tag for the language you're coding in, as any answer would clearly need that information.

Comment: Normally on StackOverflow coders are only willing to help you if you show that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DataModel> models = new List<DataModel>();
            var lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Temp\\PASS-FAIL STATUS.txt").ToArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i = i + 3)
            {
                var number = lines[i].Replace("Number:", "");
                var status = lines[i+1].Replace("Status:", "");
                var dateTime = lines[i+2].Replace("Date:", "");

                models.Add(new DataModel {
                    Number = number,
                    Status = status,
                    Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "M/d/yyyy h:m tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                });
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class DataModel
        {
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: thank you Sir, that was  really helpful !